# Do I need a work visa as a US student traveling to Germany for under 90 days?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, germany, us-citizens, work

I am an American student in the United States who is planning to travel to Germany this summer for a month and a half. I will be working there.

According to Article 14 in the employment ordinance
, "(2) No consent shall be required for the granting of a residence permit to students and pupils from foreign universities and technical colleges for a period of up to 90 days during a period of twelve months, which has been mediated by the Federal Employment Agency."

Does this mean that I don't need a visa? I already have some sort of authorization from the German Federal Employment Agency. Is this enough?

Comment: I believe this is correct.  Work authorization and authorized presence are considered separately.  Because you will be in the Schengen area for less than 90 days, you do not need a visa.  Do note that if you are in Germany for 45 days then you will not be able to spend more than 45 days in other Schengen countries during the same summer.

Comment: Is your work related to being a student?  (e.g. You are paid to be a lab assistant, course instructor etc) Or is your work unrelated to being a student?  (e.g. You are working as a bartender, tour guide or camp councilor, etc in a capacity unrelated to being a student during an academic break.)

Comment: I really think you should make sure about that working angle. *German Federation of Labor* could be an awkward translation of a either a trade union (which can't grant permits) or a Federal agency. Ask on Expatriates SE, maybe?

Comment: @phoog You are wrong. Germany does *not* issue separate work permits. The right to work in Germany for non-EEA citiziens can only be granted optionally as an 'add-on' to a residence permit.

Comment: @Sam Which act are you quoting from? Article 14 of the residence act covers unlawful presence and the text you have quoted can not be found on the internet, except in your question here.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo the quote was a direct translation from a german page. This is the link https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beschv_2013/BJNR149910013.html

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Also, it can be found in this leaflet here under chapter 3 https://www3.arbeitsagentur.de/web/wcm/idc/groups/public/documents/webdatei/mdaw/mtaw/~edisp/l6019022dstbai651347.pdf

Comment: @o.m. I was wrong--it isn't the German federation of labor, but rather the "Federal Employment Agency," or the "bundesagentur fur arbeit" in German. At the bottom of the permit that they gave me, it says (translated) "The agency for work approved: This intended holiday employment was communicated by the Federal Agency for Labor. Consent is granted on the basis of Article 14 (2) of the employment ordinance." From there, it was stamped and signed.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk the work is unrelated to being a student. I am, however, still considered full time by my university.

Comment: @Sam, would that be §14 (2) Teilzeit- und Befristungsgesetz - TzBfG?

Comment: @o.m. no--it is found in the employment ordinance. This is the link: https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beschv_2013/BJNR149910013.html

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the [German MFA](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/sid_A3689F9A59292D42CBE300F631E29311/DE/Infoservice/FAQ/VisumFuerD/02-Arbeiten.html?nn=350374) (translated from German)

> Citizens of Australia, Israel, Japan, Canada, New Zealand, South Korea and **the US can also obtain the necessary residence permit after entry**.

So no, you do **not** need a visa, but can apply for a residence permit through the migration office (*Ausländerbehörde*) once in Germany.

Comment: He doesn't need, and will not be granted, a residence permit, because he won't be staying for more than 90 days.

Comment: You won't need a visa according to this: https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/service/fragenkatalog-node/01-visumnoetig/606470 (the quote above is wrong as you are not going to study in Germany).

Comment: But you will have to register at the Einwohnermeldeamt (with confirmation from your landlord) immediately after taking a residence. Depending on the city, this requires an online registration beforehand - look at the webpage of the municipality. You don't need a working visa as you will not be working for more than 90 days within 12 months and your job was  communicated by the BA. So relax and enjoy your stay - welcome to Germany :-)